# In-App Purchase not Cleared for Sale in Sandbox

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to test my new in-app purchase code.  I have a few items set up in iTunes Connect.  I've marked one of them as NOT cleared for sale, but it is still returned in the SKProductsResponse products property, instead of the invalidProductIdentifiers property.  Is there some other way to determine whether a product is available?  Is this a common problem with the sandbox?  Could I be doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invalid identiers are not the same as not cleared for sale. the docs state:

An array of product identifier strings that were not recognized by the Apple App Store. (read-only)

AFAIK there is no programmatic way to identify cleared for sale.

Comment: The docs also state:

The store might not recognize the identifier for a number of reasons; it might be misspelled, marked unavailable for sale, or changes you have made in iTunes Connect have not propagated to all of the App Store servers.

Which strongly implies that a product that is not cleared for sale would end up in the invalid list.

Comment: I wouldn't count on that in the sandbox.

Comment: But can I count on that in production?  I guess it doesn't matter, since it's completely out of my hands.  I'll just be sure to mention to our producers that users may still be able to purchase items that we've marked unavailable for sale.

Comment: I am sure in prod this is the case. Sandbox is more forgiving for testing.

Comment: Can someone confirm this please?

Comment: I can confirm this. Cleared for sale are hidden in production envioronment, while are still visible in sandbox mode